# Wanting height of two objects to match in spite of expanding content

Tags: html, css, position, height

I have a page that has three main section:

- project-arrow-box
- white-green
- light-gray

`project-arrow-box` and `light-gray` are on the left side of the page and `white-green` is on the right. I am wanting `light-gray` and `white-green`'s bottom to meet at the same point and touch my footer. My `white-green`'s section will change size based if validation errors are made or whatever the case may be. On different screen sizes these two divs (`light-gray` and `white-green`) very in placement. Sometimes `light-gray` surpasses `white-green` and vise versa. Again, I want the end/bottom of those two divs to touch my footer regardless of the screen size.

I have tried adding `bottom: 0;` to both of `light-gray` and `white-green`, but this did not help. I have `white-green`'s height set to auto, so it adapts to the expanding nature of this div. This happened before the footer, so the footer has nothing to do with any of these issues.

What can I do so this becomes possible?

[image]

```css
.project_arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  /*background: rgb(69,186,149);*/
  background: #00a16d;
  border: 4px solid #00a16d;
  width: 33%;
  height: 800px;
  z-index: 99;
}

#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 30% 13%;
}

.white-green {
  background-color: rgb(241, 250, 247);
  width: 66.56%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 55;
  margin-left: 33.4%;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#white-green-section {
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.light-gray {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 33.5%;
  padding-top: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.light-gray-container {
  left: 15%;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project_arrow_box">
  <div id="project-content-wrap">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="white-green">
    <div id="white-green-section">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="light-gray">
    <div class="light-gray-container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`Flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}

.one {
  background: #A1EB88;
  flex: 100vh;
}

.two {
  flex: 100vh;
  background: #F2BB7C;
}

.three {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="one">One</div>
    <div class="two">Two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: What does `flex: 1;` mean in the `.three` class?

Comment: It means that it will take rest of remaining width that is left after `.left` div take his `33%` because of this `flex: 0 0 33%;` As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/156/ this will happen if you change to `flex: 0 0 70%;`

Comment: What does the `flex: 0 0 33%;` justify? Obviously 33% of the screen, but what are the two zeroes for? Top and bottom?

Comment: First zero means don't grow second don't shrink and `33%` is basis. You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex. It is same as this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/158/

Comment: For some reason my `white-green` div (your number 3) won't go all the way to the footer? Here is the real page http://www.optimumwebdesigns.com/discuss-project

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` and `margin-left` form `white-green`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox is likely the simplest way to pull that off:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="project-arrow-box">
      <p>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="light-grey">
      <p>

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="white-green">
    <p>

    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, vero?
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container, .left-container, .white-green {
  display: -webkit-box;  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6, BB7 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Safari 6.1+. iOS 7.1+, BB10 */
  display: flex;         /* NEW, Spec - Firefox, Chrome, Opera */
  margin: 0;
}

.left-container {
  display: -webkit-box; 
  display: -ms-flexbox;  
  display: -webkit-flex; 
  display: flex;         
  flex-direction: column;
}

.project-arrow-box {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}

.light-grey {
  background-color: #aaa;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}

.white-green {
  background-color: #ccFFcc;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1em;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/bL2ymhps/1/